# Unable to configure native2ascii plugin for maven

Tags: java, maven

I have `En-Jp.properties` file for automating some test cases in Japanese locale, which has English words as key & Japanese words (ASCII) as value. 
Something like this:

```
Login:\u30ed\u30b0\u30a4\u30f3
```

I first tried with Java's `native2ascii` tool for 2-3 words of Japanese which is working fine. Now when this file is growing with n-number of key-value pair. I tried using `native2ascii-maven-plugin`, configuring as described [here](http://ma.juii.net/blog/maven2-native2ascii).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
         <src>src/main/resources</src>
         <dest>target/classes</dest>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>native2ascii-utf8</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>native2ascii</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                 <includes>En-jp.properties</includes>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

However, I am getting below error,

> Unable to parse configuration of mojo
>
> org.codehaus.mojo:native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:native2ascii
>   for parameter includes: Cannot assign configuration entry 'includes'
>   with value 'En-jp.properties' of type java.lang.String to property of
>   type java.lang.String[]

What is missing in `pom.xml`? Is the version of plugin too old to work for this scenario? I am also doubtful if I am following right path (using Maven plugin) for getting ASCII value for entire properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag `<includes>` should contain a list of element, not a single element. That means you need to add `<include>` subtag to this tag.

It should be:

```xml
<includes>
    <include>En-jp.properties</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: Oh yes, that was silly mistake from my side. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I have another doubt, if I have to use this plugin, what is the correct format of properties file? `Login:ログイン` is it correct? Will the plugin convert that value in ASCII code?

Comment: @mk08 Yes, the plugin will convert your characters to their ASCII sequence.